# Configure azure virtual machine with .Net 4

Tags: .net, azure, virtual-machine

I am new to windows azure. I just created a virtual machine in windows azure. I need to install .Net 4 framework in it. But I am unable to download it from microsoft website using virtual machine's browser.

Comment: If you installed a server version you might face the browser restriction. Just add *.microsoft.com to the trusted domains and allow downloads in the security settings and that should do.

Comment: please provide additional information about error while downloading, may be in step-by-step format. May be standalone installer helps? http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=17718

Comment: I added microsoft.com to the trusted domains, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you allow downloads in the security settings?

Comment: What does "but it still doesn't work" mean exactly. Please provide some more info on the error or message.

Comment: yes i enabled downloads in security settings. When I click on download button, it shows the message "thank you for downloading", but no file is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

try this...

If you install `.Net 4 framework` in `azure` virtual machine the best way is-

Download `.Net 4 framework` in your local machine not `Azure` and after that simply copy and paste this download setup in Azure virtual machine and run this setup  after successfully install delete this setup.

May be it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try:

- Go to Windows Update on the VM and .NET 4 should be presented as an optional component to install.
- Go into Server Manager and disable IE ESC, close and reopen the browser, and try downloading again.

Thanks,
Ashok